# Is it possible to reduce Redshift load with Presto?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, presto

I have quite high-utilised `Redshift` cluster and `Prestodb` cluster.
Let's assume that it's impossible to rescale Redshift cluster in my case.

Is it make sense to setup `Redshift Connector` for Presto and run some complex queries on Presto instead of Redshift?

Would Presto propagate whole query to Redshift or just load data from it (quite cheap operation I guess) and join and aggregate it on Presto side?

Comment: Why do you consider moving data to be "quite cheap"? How much data are you moving, and what's your bandwidth? If you are performing frequent queries, you'll probably be better off doing an unload to S3 and using Presto to query those files.

Comment: I would like to avoid such manual unload, but if Presto (and Redshift Connector) can do it for me, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "Redshift Connector for Presto" simply *calls* an Amazon Redshift cluster. Therefore, it would be creating load on *both* Presto and Redshift.

It would be useful when trying to join Redshift data to some other type of data that is accessible to Presto, but it would not *reduce* the load on a Redshift cluster.

Instead, one option would be to store data in S3 instead of inside the Redshift cluster. This data could then be accessed as a **Redshift external table** *and* as a Presto table. This would allow you to "shift load" between the two systems.